# MSVC Clone C++ function

Tags: c++, templates

I have some code that is responsible for making a new function given a function typedef, aka 'clone a function by type'. It mostly works. However, I want to add a safe guard that explicitly forces the lambda clone to match the return type of the given typedef. This is so that users get nicer errors when they return the wrong type from the lambda body. This is what I have that does not work:

```
typedef void(*PKNORMAL_ROUTINE)(void* NormalContext, void* SystemArgument1, void* SystemArgument2);
typedef unsigned long(__stdcall* tNtQueueApcThread)(void* ThreadHandle, PKNORMAL_ROUTINE ApcRoutine, void* NormalContext, void* SystemArgument1, void* SystemArgument2);

uint64_t hkNtQueueapcThread = NULL;
tNtQueueApcThread pNtQueueApcthread = (tNtQueueApcThread)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueueApcThread");
typedef PLH::callback_type_t<decltype(pNtQueueApcthread)> h_NtQueueapcThread_t; 
PLH::callback_type_t<decltype(pNtQueueApcthread)>(h_NtQueueapcThread) = PLH::make_callback(pNtQueueApcthread, [](auto... _args) 
    -> PLH::callback_return_type_t<decltype(pNtQueueApcthread)> {
    std::cout << "hkNtQueueApcThread!" << std::endl; 
    auto ret = PLH::FnCast(hkNtQueueapcThread, pNtQueueApcthread)(_args...); 
    return ret;
});
```

The problematic line is:

```
-> PLH::callback_return_type_t<decltype(pNtQueueApcthread)>
```

I have verified callback_return_type_t evaluates to 'unsinged long' in this case.

The following however works when I type the return value explicitly myself:

```
-> unsigned long
```

Why would it work when I explicitly force the return type, but not when I force the return type using my callback_return_type_t? Here is the full source as a test:

https://godbolt.org/z/x5bhvrWaE

If you change the compiler it will fail under MSVC, but succeed under Clang and GCC. How can I get this to work everywhere, and why might it be failing?

Comment: This question should be tagged with the C++ version. Can't reproduce with C++20: https://godbolt.org/z/s11rG1ocx

Comment: "that does not work" is not a good problem description. How does it not work, any compiler error, wrong deduced type, what else?

Comment: <source>(59): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'F' to 'Ret (__cdecl *)(void *,PKNORMAL_ROUTINE,void *,void *,void *)'

Comment: The error can be reproduced by setting the VS version to < 19.30 which seems to by my problem. Even with the C++ 20 flag

Comment: Please [edit] the full compiler output into your question